# getting data from web link

Tags: php, get

When i type the following URL:

> `http://localhost/googleOAUTH/user_info.php#state=try_sample_request&access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMC4E_JpLyJIkG2MERuOdo1buECC7o6mUEGyeYCymazIoyQIhJ2j70sdTgq7S-yET2hjsNoRCaX2Cbhp7f2fIfQeHIb2e6UYf4moZdeGIpGmZ3tNIprLccoQldt9juy0uMqHt7BRMlWxdDIdo6bTbNUa&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

```
<?php
 print($_GET['access_token']);
?>
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: access_token in C:\xampp\htdocs\googleOAUTH\user_info.php on line 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fragment part (`#whatever`) should come after query string parameters (`?access_token=....&....&...`).

So your URL needs to be

```
http://localhost/googleOAUTH/user_info.php?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMC4E_JpLyJIkG2MERuOdo1buECC7o6mUEGyeYCymazIoyQIhJ2j70sdTgq7S-yET2hjsNoRCaX2Cbhp7f2fIfQeHIb2e6UYf4moZdeGIpGmZ3tNIprLccoQldt9juy0uMqHt7BRMlWxdDIdo6bTbNUa&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=profile%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile#state=try_sample_request
```